# How to use jQuery dependant plugins in create-react-app

Tags: jquery, import, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I want to use bootstrap and other jQuery plugins (datepicker, carousel, ...) in my React app which uses `create-react-app`.

Here is how I import jQuery and bootstrap:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
```

And I get the following error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 5:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Note that I don't want to use `react-bootstrap` package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case for using `bootstrap` or `bootstrap-datepicker` I needed to `require` it instead of importing it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-datepicker');
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: Thanks for very much, you saved my day too.

Answer (score 7):

to avoid having to `require`, one can also create a separate file to load jquery, eg.

jquery-loader.js:

```
import $ from "jquery"

window.$ = $
window.jQuery = $
```

and then

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './jquery-loader';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
```