# create-react-app ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Getting this error when using with create-react-app

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I have this in my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
//import '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';

import jQuery from 'jquery';
import '../node_modules/product-xxx/dist/js/product-xxx.min.js'; // this file uses jQuery
```

I already tried still no use

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;
```

This works if I load jQuery from CDN in the public/index.html
jQuery version is 3x

Any pointers?

**Update**

jQuery is used in the module product-xxx like this

```
+function(t) {
    "use strict";
    function e() {
        var t = document.createElement("bootstrap")
          , e = {
            WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd",
            MozTransition: "transitionend",
            OTransition: "oTransitionEnd otransitionend",
            transition: "transitionend"
        };
        for (var i in e)
            if (void 0 !== t.style[i])
                return {
                    end: e[i]
                };
        return !1
    }
    t.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function(e) {
        var i = !1
          , o = this;
        t(this).one("bsTransitionEnd", function() {
            i = !0
        });
        var n = function() {
            i || t(o).trigger(t.support.transition.end)
        };
        return setTimeout(n, e),
        this
    }
    ,
    t(function() {
        t.support.transition = e(),
        t.support.transition && (t.event.special.bsTransitionEnd = {
            bindType: t.support.transition.end,
            delegateType: t.support.transition.end,
            handle: function(e) {
                return t(e.target).is(this) ? e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments) : void 0
            }
        })
    })
}(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

To install jquery with npm

`npm install jquery --save`

After you do that, on every page you must have this where you are using jquery

`import $ from 'jquery';`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed jquery in your `package.json`? May be you can try this [How to use jQuery dependant plugins in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088235/how-to-use-jquery-dependant-plugins-in-create-react-app) or this issue [#679](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/679)

Comment: Its already there in package.json under dependencies "jquery": "^3.3.1",

Comment: @mrale81 don't put questions in answers, if you have questions, ask them in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `import jQuery from 'jquery';` in every file that you are using it

Comment: My understanding is src/index.js does that. I have also included it every file but not working.

Comment: you need to add the jquery import inside the product-xxx js file

Comment: anyway it will be better if you use a cdn version, and then use in your code `window.jQuery`